# How to disable directory files from accessing?

Tags: directory

Hi team how do I disable my wordpress site directory from accessing?
example url: http://mysite.ph/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Orders-Export-2017-July-04-1712.csv.txt

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it for security purpose you can use following steps:
add index.php file to each folder that you don't want to show the content of.

```
<?php // Just leave the index.php file blank
```

And second way to reduce insecurity is to use

```
if(!defined('ABSPATH')){ exit; }
```

inside every php files to no access that file directly.
I hope it helps.
And you are welcome to explore further on your own.
Good Luck!!!

Comment: this protect only PHP files. in addition of this, you can deny access of a whole directory on Apache with a file `.htaccess` containing `Deny from All`.